# create custom commands in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create some commands in Python and it will read from a text file.

Let's say file name is `commands.txt`

```
ADD 5 4
SUBSTRACT 6 5
```

Output :-

```
9
1
```

We will pass the text input file like,

python myfile.py commands.txt

I can add or substract in Python but how to read the command and use it from a text file,

myfile.py :-

```
sum = 5+4
print sum
substract = 6-5
print substract
```

Comment: Your code: does not read a file, does not split the lines inside the read file, does not attempt to use any kind of math based on whatever was split from the file. Your code: does overwrite the built-in `sum()` function with a local value of 9 (thats bad). Please show your effort and exact problem you have with the task set to you - else this is just a "do my work for me" question that will get downvoted and closed fast.

Comment: In case you want to edit your question, delete it (so nobody downvotes it while you bring its content up to par) and undelete it afterwards.

Comment: For a simple way you can open the file, read it line by line in a loop where you split each line you get into the its string elements and then based on the first line string call a corresponding function and pass it the remaining strings from the same line as parameters. I suggest you try yourself first and then edit your question to show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

this sort of thing can get complicated quickly, a very simple/naive solution that makes lots of assumptions would be something like:

```
def do_add(a, b):
  return float(a) + float(b)

def do_subtract(a, b):
  return float(a) - float(b)

cmds = {
  'ADD': do_add,
  'SUBSTRACT': do_subtract,
}

def process(line):
  cmd, *args = line.split()
  return cmds[cmd](*args)

with open('input.txt') as fd:
  for line in fd:
    print(process(line))
```

Comment: Basic arithmetic operations are also in the `operator` module --> `{'ADD': operator.add, ...}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code. It assumes that you have a file called `commands.txt` with the contents mentioned in your question. Make sure you don't write SUB**S**TRACT, but SUBTRACT:

```
def subtract(args):
    return int(args[0]) - int(args[1])

def add(args):
    return int(args[0]) + int(args[1])

FN_LOOKUP = {
    'ADD': add,
    'SUBTRACT': subtract,
}

with open('commands.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Remove whitespace/linebreaks
        line = line.strip()
        # Command is the first string before a whitespace
        cmd = line.split(' ')[0]
        # Arguments are everything after that, separated by whitespaces
        args = line.split(' ')[1:]
        if cmd in FN_LOOKUP:
            # If the command is in the dict, execute it with its args
            result = FN_LOOKUP[cmd](args)
            args_str = ', '.join(args)
            print(f'{cmd}({args_str}) = {result}')
        else:
            # If not, raise an error
            raise ValueError(f'{cmd} is not a valid command!')
```